# Program C stops when pointer receives value of variable

Tags: c, pointers, variables, struct

My function is returning the following error when executing the program: Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005).

Until the moment I assign the inputs to the variables, it works. However, when the program is going to assign the values of the variables to the pointers, the program stops.

```
void Cadastrar(pessoas *p){
    char nome[50];
    int idade;
    char sexo;
    char endereco [200];

    printf("Digite o nome: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s",nome);
    fflush(stdin);

    printf("Digite a idade: ");
    scanf("%d",&idade);

    printf("Escolha o sexo: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    sexo = getchar();
    fflush(stdin);

    printf("Digite o endereco: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s",endereco);
    fflush(stdin);

    strncpy(p->nome,nome, sizeof(nome));
    p->idade = idade;
    p->sexo = sexo;
    strncpy(p->endereco,endereco, sizeof(nome));

}
```

Comment: By now the older question is better. Please work on that.

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` is undefined behaviour. Don't do it and don't learn from those who do. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin  Also, `strncpy(p->endereco,endereco, sizeof(nome));` one of these things is not like the other two. Also `strncpy` is a dangerous function that should almost never be used on its own.

Comment: If you get the inputs read (so `endereco` is given a value), then the problem is almost certainly in the structure that `p` points to.  You've not provided any evidence to show how the structure is defined as a type, nor how you've initialized `p`.  There's a moderate chance that `p` is a null pointer; there's a chance that it simply points somewhere random because it was not initialized.  But we can't help with that because you've not provided the information to allow us to do so.

Comment: You need to show the code that calls `Cadastrar` and the relevant variable declarations. The problem is most likely _there_